# PHP while loop into JSON arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to create JSON arrays to postback to them to Slack with info from a while loop.

Here is the code I've came up with:

```
$adset = null;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($leadsAdsetsQuery)) {
  if ($row["adset"] != $adset) {
    $adset = $row["adset"];
    echo "{$adset}<br>";
  }
  echo $row["id"] . "<br>";
}
```

The output is:

```
Adset Name 1
20
Adset Name 2
34
Adset Name 3
11
```

And I need to have a new JSON array for each Adset Name with the number of leads structure like this:

```
  'attachments' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'fallback' => 'XXX',
      'text' => 'XXX',
      'fields' => 
      array (  
        0 => 
        array (
          'title' => 'Adset Name 1',
          'value' => '20',
          'short' => true,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'title' => 'Adset Name 2',
          'value' => '34',
          'short' => true,
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'title' => 'Adset Name 3',
          'value' => '11',
          'short' => true,
        ),
      ),
      'color' => '#F35A00',
    ),
  )
```

I'm not a big expert in JSON nor in PHP and google didn't seem to help.

Comment: Don't try to build a JSON string.  Just build a PHP array, then convert it to JSON before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
   $arrResult = array();
   $arrResult['attachments'] = array();

   // add 0 'fallback'  'text'  'fields  'color'
   $arrResult['attachments'][0] = array(
      'fallback' => 'XXX',
      'text' => 'XXX',
      'fields' => array(),
      'color' => '#F35A00'
   );

   // add 0 'fields'
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($leadsAdsetsQuery)){
      if(!empty($row['adset']) and !empty($row['id'])){
         $arrResult['attachments'][0]['fields'][] = array(
            'title' => $row["adset"],
            'value' => $row['id'],
            'short' => true
         );
      };
   };

   // print JSON 
   echo json_encode($arrResult, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```